# Recursion between two list of text files

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, recursion

I have the following question.
Let say I have a list of text files in a folder:

```
D:/Users/Roger/A
```

And another list of text files in another folder:

```
D:/Users/Roger/Reports
```

(The lists are the complete path to them), and they are ordered alphabetically so they match 1:1 for example:

```
FOLDER_A = ["D:/Users/Roger/A/a.txt", "D:/Users/Roger/A/b.txt"]
FOLDER_B = ["D:/Users/Roger/B/a.txt", "D:/Users/Roger/A/b.txt"]
```

I made a dictionary using both lists

```
Dict = {}
for i in range(len(FOLDER_A)):
    Dict[FOLDER_A[i]] = FOLDER_B[i]
    sorted(Dict.items())
```

Later on, I copied the information of `a.txt` in folder `A` to the `a.txt` file in folder `B`, doing a `for` loop, that iterated between the `key` and `value` of the dictionary.

**My question:** Is there a form to this by using some kind of recursion? instead of iterating through `k,v` in a dictionary with python 2.7.??
Thank you very much!

Comment: You want to sort items using recursion?

Comment: what do you mean by " Is there a form to this"

Comment: @user2695448 Maybe I am using the wrong Term. I just want to iterate in 10 files, in one folder to copy their info in 10 other files located in another folder

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need any recursion here. You can iterate through the files in the first folder and compare the names and then copy the information from the in the first folder to the file in the second folder, some thing like that:

```
import os

folder1= "folder1"
folder2 = "folder2"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder1):
    for file in files:
    if file in os.listdir(folder2):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder1, file)
            file1_path = os.path.join(folder2, file)
        if os.path.isfile(file1_path):
        with open(file_path) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            with open(file1_path, 'a') as f1:
                f1.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a form of recursion, as with all iterative algorithms there will be an alternate form. However, the recursive version is rarely used because of the likelihood of generating a stack overflow which would be due to the length of the list being longer than the stack space.

Recursive algorithms can be very expressive, but to me, the organisation of the data is asking to be iterated over.

btw your `dict` can be created with a dictionary comprehension:

```
Dict = { FOLDER_A[i]]:FOLDER_B[i] for i in range(len(FOLDER_A)) }
```